# What control style should I use for Voxatron?

Tags: controllers, voxatron

I picked up the [Voxatron](http://www.lexaloffle.com/voxatron.php) alpha today and I'm finding it pretty difficult to play with WASD and a mouse since there's no way to tell if your mouse is positioned left, right, above or below the player. It's a fairly traditional two-joystick shooter but it's a PC game so I'm stuck on what control style I should attempt next.

Is there a setting I'm missing that makes the mouse style bearable? Or should I break down and find a way to pair a controller with two joysticks to my Mac?

Comment: In their latest Blog post, they mention adding more control configurations into the next version: http://www.lexaloffle.com/bbs/?tid=355

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the arrow keys and Z and X (or C and V) for Jump and Shoot respectively.  Once you start shooting in one direction, your character locks in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

There was a "reticule" added in one of the later updates (think it was 0.1.5) that shows where you're aiming with the mouse.